# Avoid Vim keeping closed buffers open in the background

Tags: vim

After doing a complete re-setup of my Vim environment using various standard extensions there is one behavior that annoys me quite much:

When I open a file in a split window and close that window again (":wq") Vim seems to keep the file buffer open in the background. When I now try to open the file in a different shell tab in a new Vim instance, the swap file still exists, what keeps me from editing the file.

I suppose there is a setting which makes Vim keep buffers open but hidden when I close the split, but I could not find out which one it is. What I actually desire is, that Vim really closes the buffers when I close the splits, so that I can open the corresponding files again in a parallel Vim session.

What I expect is, that the buffer is closed as soon as the last window showing it is closed via ":q".

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Check the value of the `hidden` option using `:set hidden?`. By default, vim has this set to `nohidden`, which should produce the behaviour you're asking for; buffers are unloaded when they become abandoned (meaning no windows are displaying them). It's possible that this setting got set to `hidden`, which causes the behaviour you're experiencing; buffers become hidden when abandoned.

Do `:help 'hidden'` for more information.

Comment: That was exactly what I was missing. Thx! :)

Answer (score 2):

I think you're confusing buffers with windows. A good explanation of the difference can be found [here](http://blog.sanctum.geek.nz/buffers-windows-tabs/).

I'd also suggest this [read](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Deleting_a_buffer_without_closing_the_window). It has a script example that closes buffers without closing the window, which should be the effect you described.

Cheers, I hope that helps.

Comment: Sorry for confusing the terminology. I updated the question to have it right an tried to clarify which behavior I expect. As far as I could see, both references don't explain on this, do they?

Answer (score 1):

You are looking for the `:bw[ipeout]`.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure how you are closing a split, for example using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>W</kbd><kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>o</kbd> in the other window or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>W</kbd><kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>q</kbd>, but I don't think this is supposed to close the buffer as well. Spliting is only a window management method, not a a buffer management one.

If in a split, you want to close a buffer and its window, why don't you use `:bd`? It will explicitly close the buffer.

Comment: I typically close the Split using ":q", which I expect to close the window as well as the buffer. At least that is the behavior I'm used to.

Comment: @tobyS: thanks for the clarification. If you check `:help :q` it does say it will only quit the *window*, it does not say anything on the buffer. So it is the normal behaviour.