# Current buffer in Vim get replaced when opening a file

Tags: vim, macvim

When opening a new file via `:E` command (not with ctrl-P plugin, this works fine!), both Vim and MacVim (8.0.1098) discard contents of the current buffer, so it becomes impossible to switch to if by using `:bn!` and `:bp!` commands.

However, if I modify the contents of current buffer, then open another file and only then try to close MacVim, I get a warning message about unsaved file. So the buffer must be still hanging somewhere?

Also, if I split the window and open a file then, both buffers remain open.

I do have `set hidden` in my `.vimrc` and running `:set hidden?` returns `hidden`, meaning that scrolling through hidden buffers with `:bn!` and `:bp!` should work, but it doesn't.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The fact that ctrlP had no issues opening & switching buffers suggested there was something wrong with netrw.

Upon closer inspection it turned out that my netrw plugin was out-of-date.

Upgrading to v162j (via Vundle) solved the problem.

Answer (score 1):

> When opening a new file via `:E` command, both Vim and MacVim (8.0.1098) discard contents of the current buffer, so it becomes impossible to switch to if by using `:bn!` and `:bp!` commands.

The behavior you describe is inconsistent with:

- the expected behavior,
- and the behavior I get with the exact same version.

To test it in a repeatable way:

```
$ vim -Nu NORC a.txt     starts Vim with a.txt
:Explore                 replaces the current buffer with a netrw buffer
(press <CR> on b.txt)    replaces the netrw buffer with b.txt
:bn (or :bp)             replaces the current buffer with a.txt
```

> However, if I modify the contents of current buffer, then open another file and only then try to close MacVim, I get a warning message about unsaved file. So the buffer must be still hanging somewhere?

Yes, it's almost certainly in the buffer list. Try `:ls` for listed buffers and `:ls!` for all buffers. `:ls` should show you `a.txt` at #1 and `b.txt` at #3 whereas `:ls!` should show you the same, plus the netrw buffer at #2.

Also, see `:help 'hidden'`.

--- EDIT ---

For reference, the expected output of `:ls!` should be:

```
1      "a.txt"                        line 1
2u#h-  "~/"                           line 11
3 %a   "~/b.txt"                      line 1
```

Note that the only "unlisted" buffer should be the Netrw buffer: `~/` at #2.

Did you change anything to any Vim-related file or directory outside of `$HOME`?

Comment: Tried that command line, getting same behaviour, although I can see it in `:ls!`:

```1u     "a.txt"                        line 1
  2u#h-  "~/"     line 29
  3 %a   "~/b.txt" line 1```

Comment: Found this question - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15945157/avoid-vim-keeping-closed-buffers-open-in-the-background but my `set hidden?` returns `nohidden` which should be the wanted mode? 

Flipping it to `hidden` returns proper behaviour. Bizarre.

Comment: Yes, `set hidden` is pretty much obligatory.

Comment: Well, I have `set hidden` in my `.vimrc` and it doesn't seem to help. Could it be overridden somewhere else?

Comment: The `u` in your output of `:ls!` means "unlisted". This is not normal *at all*.